# (Angularjs) Data not synchronising between views sharing one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, updating

I have two views sharing the same controller and use a service to pass data between them.

Let's say we have view1 and view2, a button pressed in view2 should change something in view1.

When view1 is charged, the data stored in the service is its $scope (the $scope of the instance of the controller if I'm not mistaking).

So when the button is pressed in view2, the service updates something on the $scope of view1. The thing is, it works well when view1 and view2 are charged simultaneously (view2 is a menu hidden on the right and is always there).

But when I switch page (I charge view3) and come back to view1 (keep in mind that view2 isn't recharged) it won't work anymore, and it feels like my views don't use the same service since when I check in both of them the data is different !!

I don't know if I explained it well but if you have some ideas on why it doesn't work I'd be glad.
Here's some of the code :

my routes :

```
 $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/presentation.html'
      }).
      when('/action', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/main.html'
      }).
      when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/about.html'
      });
```

in the html :

```
        <li ng-class="{active: routeIs('/')}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: routeIs('/action')}"><a href="#/action">Action</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: routeIs('/about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
```

my service :

```
North.factory('urlupdate', function() {
var factory = {};
var propertyListener;

factory.setPropertyHost = function(value) {
propertyListener.host = value;
};

factory.setPropertyActionport = function(value) {
propertyListener.actionPort = value;
};

factory.setPropertyindexPort = function(value) {
propertyListener.indexPort = value;
};

factory.setPropertyserviceport = function(value) {
propertyListener.serviceport = value;
};

factory.registerForPropertyUpdate = function(listener) {
propertyListener = listener;
};

factory.getProperty = function() {
    return propertyListener.host;
}

factory.getRegister = function() {
    return propertyListener;
}

return factory;    
});
```

The part of my controller :

```
North.controller('northcontroller', ["$scope",'myService','location','urlupdate','$rootScope','$timeout',

function ($scope,myService,location,urlupdate,$rootScope,$timeout) {

$scope.begin = function(){
//some code

    urlupdate.registerForPropertyUpdate($scope);
    alert(urlupdate.getRegister()); // shows an object
}

function updatevariable(url, port) {
    alert(urlupdate.getRegister()); // shows a different object, or even "undefined" if the main page wasn't on "view1" when it loaded.
    $rootScope.host=url;
    $rootScope.actionPort=9000+port;
    $rootScope.indexport=9001+port;
    $rootScope.serviceport=9002+port;

    urlupdate.setPropertyHost($rootScope.host);    
    urlupdate.setPropertyActionport($rootScope.actionPort);
    urlupdate.setPropertyindexPort($rootScope.indexport)
    urlupdate.setPropertyserviceport($rootScope.serviceport)


}
```

The function updatevariable is called in view2.

I have no idea why it stops working after my route is modified I'm kind of new to angularjs.

I you want to see more code I'll provide, I just want to know if I forgot something or if there's something to know about route/services/controllers that I missed.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle

Comment: I will try but it will take some time since I have several html pages

Comment: My suggestion would be to use $scope.$emit and $scope.$broadcast for your purposes isnstead of creating a fatory of urlupdate - Reference http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I managed to make it work with $scope.$broadcast and using two separates controllers....but when I change route/page it's not working anymore. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is define `propertyListener` object the add properties to it

```
var propertyListener = {};
```

Comment: He uses registerForPropertyUpdate to store $scope .. so its not necessary to use it

Comment: Thanks for reminding me !
Sadly it doesn't solve my problem :/